# event listener firing on its own on page load

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Event listener is firing on its own when page loads but want to make it fire only via click of the button. What is the way to tackle this problem?Here is the code:

```
class IntroAnimations{
    constructor() {

        //global variables
        this.jsLoadingCta    = document.querySelector('#js-loading-cta');
        this.tlRemoveLoading = new TimelineMax();

        //event listeners: ISSUE HERE
        this.jsLoadingCta.addEventListener('click', this.removeLoadingContent(this.tlRemoveLoading));

        //method calls:
        this.loadAnimations(this.jsLoadingCta);

    };

    removeLoadingContent(tl){

        let jsLoadOverlay = document.querySelector('#js-overlay-load');

        tl
        .to(jsLoadOverlay, 1, {width: '100%', ease: Power4.easeInOut})
        .set(jsLoadOverlay, {left: 'auto', right: 0})
        .to(jsLoadOverlay, 1, {width: '0%', ease: Power4.easeInOut})

    }

    loadAnimations(loadingCta){

        //variables
        let jsloadingCompanyintrotextset1 = document.querySelector('#js-loading-company-intro-text-set-1'),
            jsloadingCompanyintrotextset2 = document.querySelector('#js-loading-company-intro-text-set-2'),
            jsloadingCompanyintrotextset3 = document.querySelector('#js-loading-company-intro-text-set-3'),
            tlIntro                       = new TimelineMax();


        //instaniation of SplitText
        let companyIntro1 = new SplitText().configureDomElement(jsloadingCompanyintrotextset1),
            companyIntro2 = new SplitText().configureDomElement(jsloadingCompanyintrotextset2),
            companyIntro3 = new SplitText().configureDomElement(jsloadingCompanyintrotextset3);


        //GSAP Animations
        tlIntro
        .set([companyIntro1, companyIntro2, companyIntro3], {x: 20, opacity: 0})
        .staggerTo(companyIntro1, 1, {x: 0, opacity: 1, ease: Power4.easeOut}, .02)
        .staggerTo(companyIntro2, 1, {x: 0, opacity: 1, ease: Power4.easeOut}, .02, '-=.95')
        .staggerTo(companyIntro3, 1, {x: 0, opacity: 1, ease: Power4.easeOut}, .02, '-=.9')
        .to(loadingCta, 1, {x: 0, opacity: 1, autoAlpha: 1, ease: Power4.easeOut}, '-=.9')

    };
};
```

Thank you. Why is this happening? Does it need to be bind?

Comment: When you use parenthesis like this, it will fire at load `this.removeLoadingContent(this.tlRemoveLoading)` ... you need it to be e.g. `this.removeLoadingContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use parenthesis like this, `this.removeLoadingContent(this.tlRemoveLoading)`, it will fire at load.

You need it to be e.g. `this.removeLoadingContent`

---

Since all you do with `this.tlRemoveLoading` is pass a `new TimelineMax()`, instead try to do something like this

```
    //event listeners: ISSUE HERE
    this.jsLoadingCta.addEventListener('click', this.removeLoadingContent);
```

```
removeLoadingContent(){

    let jsLoadOverlay = document.querySelector('#js-overlay-load');
    let tl = new TimelineMax();

    tl
    .to(jsLoadOverlay, 1, {width: '100%', ease: Power4.easeInOut})
    .set(jsLoadOverlay, {left: 'auto', right: 0})
    .to(jsLoadOverlay, 1, {width: '0%', ease: Power4.easeInOut})

}
```

Comment: okay okay what if I need to pass something into the parenthasis?

Comment: @Harpreet Then you pick the other answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe because it is being called there. Try changing it to

```
this.jsLoadingCta.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.removeLoadingContent(this.tlRemoveLoading)
})
```